# R function gsub replace only cases with "."

Tags: r

my vector has some missing values which have been marked by dot "." in my vector, I want to replace the "." by "NA" without affecting the decimal point in other values,

for exemple:

```
vect <- c( 1.1, ".", 2.5, ".", 3.0)
> vect
[1] "1.1" "."   "2.5" "."   "3"
```

I've used the gsub function to do the replacement and I'd like to get something like:

```
vect2
[1] 1.1 NA 2.5 NA 3.0
```

I've tried these commands below:

```
> gsub(".", NA, vect)
[1] NA NA NA NA NA
```

or

```
> gsub(".","NA", vect)
[1] "NANANA" "NA"     "NANANA" "NA"     "NA"
```

or

```
> gsub("\\.\\b","NA", vect)
[1] "1NA1" "NA"   "2NA5" "NA"   "3"
```

How can I tell R to replace only those missing values marked by "." without changing the decimal point of others values? Thanks :)

Comment: `as.numeric(vect)` should do

Comment: See http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html#vectors and look for 'Coercion' for *why* this happens

Comment: I do'nt know how you got those dots instead of missing value but I'm guessing it comes from import data. You may want to directly import those dots as missing values. There is a `na.strings` parameter in `read.table` (for example)

Comment: @Cath In fact there are several markers (MD, NA, or .) for missing data in the database due to the merging of 7 different original databases, and I used the read.xlsx function which I didn't find the option to precise the missing data parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `sub`.  Specify the pattern as `.` as the only character in the string and replace it with NA.  The `.` is a metacharacter which means any character, so we either escape (`\\.`) or use `fixed = TRUE` (however, using start (`^`) and end `$` of the string, the escape route is the safest.

```
as.numeric(sub("^\\.$", NA, vect))
#[1] 1.1  NA 2.5  NA 3.0
```

The usual way is just `as.numeric` as it will convert the `character` strings to `NA` with a warning.

```
as.numeric(vect)
#[1] 1.1  NA 2.5  NA 3.0
```

Comment: What does $ mean in the pattern of replacement? I've tried sub("^\\.", NA, vect) and it gives the same result.

Comment: @Lily THe `$` is a metacharacter which means the end of the string.  So there is only a `.` between the start and end of the string.  In your example, it works, because there is no string like `.cat`

Comment: Does the anti-slash mean anything here? Or we could just use `"^.$"` instead of `"^\\.$"` ?

Comment: @Lily The `.` is a metacharacter which means any character.  So, it can match `"c"` `"f"` or any other character.